# Flutter - Azure Communication Services Platform Integration (android, ios)

Tags: android, flutter, azure, video-streaming, azure-communication-services

I want to make a interview app with services like group calling for chatting involving multiple users, for android and ios using Azure Communication Services in Flutter.

There is no direct sdk in flutter for azure communication services.

As I solution I have to write custom platform specific code for android and ios, [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab).

There are platform channels to communicate between native and flutter, I am not able to get started with them and how to use them to communicate, and send streams to native code. There are very less examples available regarding platform integration. Any help appreciated.

Especially the event channels, it will be better if i can stream camera feed from ACS Call object and render it on the dart ui?

Abbr: ACS -> Azure Communication Services

I have tried to follow offical documentation but not able to use it well because is are not much detail also I am noticing same example almost everywhere, so I need a better material to follow.